# Does "code bloat" occur in C++ due to inline functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I have an interview question about C++, Does "code bloat" occur in C++ due to inline functions?

I know that this is true for templates, but what about inline functions? if yes, why.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you think is the answer?

Comment: Half-tempted to suggest dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/6607138/560648 but it's pretty specific to that author's situation

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/inline-functions#inline-and-perf

Comment: it will depend on the inline function in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `inline` keyword has little to do with inlining unfortunately. It's more about placing the function *inline in the header* rather than the inlining optimisation.

If binary size is truely a concern, there are compiler flags such as `-Os` and `-Oz` that will reduce the binary size and also reduce inlining at the cost of speed.